# unset range of keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key, unset

How can i unset a range of keys between say 70 to 80 in an array like this?

```
[63] => Computer Science and Informatics
[64] => Dentistry
[65] => Development Studies
[66] => Drama, Dance and Performing Arts
[67] => Earth Systems and Environmental Sciences
[68] => Economics and Econometrics
[69] => Education
[70] => Electrical and Electronic Engineering
[71] => English Language and Literature
[72] => Epidemiology and Public Health
[73] => European Studies
[74] => French
[75] => General Engineering and Mineral & Mining Engineering
[76] => Geography and Environmental Studies
[77] => Geography and Environmental Studies
[78] => German, Dutch and Scandinavian Languages
[79] => Health Services Research
[80] => History
[81] => History of Art, Architecture and Design
[82] => Iberian and Latin American Languages
[83] => Infection and Immunology
[84] => Italian
[85] => Law
[86] => Library and Information Management
[87] => Linguistics
[88] => Mechanical, Aeronautical and Manufacturing Engineering
[89] => Metallurgy and Materials
[90] => Middle Eastern and African Studies
```

Comment: its to remove 67 keys, so dont want to unset each individually

Answer (score 11):

You can try [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$return = array_slice($original, 0, 60)
```

then

```
$return = $return+array_slice($original, 70)
```

or

[array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$return = array_splice($original, 60, 10)
```

Comment: This works, but it's really inefficient. You're creating 3 arrays in addition to the one you start with.

Comment: Given the fact that it is a fairly small data set, I would probably go with this solution, I don't think its *efficiency* is going to have any perceptible impact on performance, plus it is readable and somewhat elegant. Voted up.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't really a shortcut to this:

```
for ($i = 70; $i <= 80; $i++)  
    unset($array[$i]);
```

Comment: +1 for this one too, its a simpler solution and gets the job done the same

Comment: It's kind of dissapointing, all the PHP coders who always ask if there's a function to do something bizarrely niche, when a for()/foreach() loop does it just fine.

Comment: Can you step forward through the array during the unset? Doesn't that cause an issue with changing the index of the next element to be unset as you move through? I would have thought you had to step through from 80 to 70, decrementing i.