# How do mass unset of an array elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unset range of keys in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352926/unset-range-of-keys-in-an-array)

I have an array $test, it contains 1000s of element with random key between 1 and 10000,
I want to unset array elements of particular key range. eg  i wanna unset elements if the key value between 500 and 600.
Now i am using **foreach** loop to do this. Any other php shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original link

[unset range of keys in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352926/unset-range-of-keys-in-an-array)

You can try [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$return = array_slice($original, 0, 60)
```

then

```
$return = $return+array_slice($original, 70)
```

or

[array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$return = array_splice($original, 60, 10)
```

Comment: This is a copied answer from another question.. You should specify that (same answer found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352926/unset-range-of-keys-in-an-array )

Comment: @MateiMihai .. link is added..

Comment: still, OP stated that the keys are random, and not incremental

Comment: Copying a noteworthy comment from @ryeguy : `This works, but it's really inefficient. You're creating 3 arrays in addition to the one you start with. `

Answer (score 4):

How about this (untested, hand-written)

```
function unsetRange($arr,$from,$to)
{
    for($i=$from;$i<=$to;$i++)
        unset($arr[$i]);
}

// Unset elements from 500 to 600
unsetRange($myArr,500,100);
```

Comment: @Mihai Iorga - I provided the code he was asking for: `I want to unset array elements of particular key range.` - Generating the numbers is out of the scope of this question/answer. (atleast IMO)